# Configure Nginx with proxy redirect for docker containers

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have two apps running in docker ie (mapserver and nginx). My nginx config is like below

```
upstream mapserver {
server mapserver:80;
}

server {

listen      80;
server_name foo.bar.com;
location / {
    root /web/;
    index index.html index.htm;
}

location /mapserver {
    proxy_pass http://mapserver/;
    proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
    port_in_redirect off;
    proxy_redirect  http://mapserver/ /mapserver/;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
}

}
```

If I navigate to http://foo.bar.com/mapserver and do a get capabilities request it works well but however the HTML content that is returned does not return the proper URL.

It returns https://foo.bar.com/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/map/test.map but what I was hoping for it to return is http://foo.bar.com/mapserver/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/map/test.map. It looks like the proxy_redirect is not working or is improperly configured. How can I fix it?

Comment: have you tried it without adding `proxy_redirect`.  `proxy_pass` should be enough to forward request to map server and get the response back.

Comment: I think proxy_redirect is not doing anything in this situation. Yes I have removed it and still, the get capabilities only return the $remote host in the HTM without appending /mapserver

Comment: does your map server look at the incoming url to generate this new url which has /mapserver missing?

Comment: Mapserver itself doesn't but in order to import the wms into QGIS or Geoserver it passes the get capabilities which result in no map being drawn because of the mising /mapserv

Comment: Try with this `proxy_pass http://mapserver/mapserver` this will proxy requests to map server at path /mapserver

Comment: It doesn't work, maybe I have to try rewrite the url using sub_filter